# A função Datediff resultou em um estouro Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(MAX(CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SS, [INICOLIGACAO],[FINALLIGACAO]), 0))),'')  AS [DURACAO_CHAMADA]

WHERE
 CONVERT(DATE,[DIA]) = '2019-10-30' 
AND [CAMPANHA] = ('1') 
GO
```

Quando eu a executo a mesma retorna o o erro:

> ```
> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
> ```

porem quando altero de segundos para minutos ou ate mesmo horas ela retorna os dados, porem preciso dos dados em segundos.

Quando é colocado o DATEDIFF_BIG() ele da o erro:

'DATEDIFF_big' is not a recognized built-in function name.

estou pegando as ligações apenas do dia anterior

o select que faço é

```
SELECT 
     ACIONAMENTO
    ,CPF
    ,DDD+TELEFONE
    ,CONTRATO
    ,ISNULL(MAX(CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,[INICOLIGAÇÃO],[FINALLIGACAO]), 0))) ,'')  AS [DURACAO_CHAMADA]
    ,OPERADOR

FROM 
    TABELA

WHERE
    CONVERT(DATE,[inicioligacao]) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-1)
     AND [campanha] IN ('1')
```

Comment: Se ocorreu estouro então é porque os dados estão errados, pois quem ficaria anos em uma ligação?

Comment: Você ainda não forneceu os dados de sua tabela.

Comment: Você mostrou a `query` que está realizando mas não mostrou ainda qual os dados da sua tabela

Comment: @Sorack poderia ser mais claro.

Comment: @PauloHenrique mais claro do que dizer que voce precisa mostrar o conjunto de dados? Estou perguntando o que tem dentro da sua tabela, que você mostre linhas, tuplas.

Answer (score 4):

Se o objetivo é calcular a duração em segundos de uma chamada telefônica, então parece que alguém ficou por anos fazendo uma ligação...

Sobre a mensagem de erro "*The datediff function resulted in an overflow*", já tive esse problema certa vez e foi quando tomei conhecimento da existência da função [DATEDIFF_BIG](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql). Ela permite valores bem maiores, mas para mim não foi a solução pois ela está disponível (acho que) a partir da versão 2016 do SQL Server e eu precisava de algo compatível com a versão 2008. Tive então que criar uma solução de contorno, bem simples até.

Se a versão do SQL Server que está a utilizar é 2016 (ou mais recente), experimente então DATEDIFF_BIG(). Mas se o contexto é duração de chamada telefônica, provavelmente os dados processados estão errados.

---

Ao final há uma conversão para TIME(0); isto faz com que uma chamada que tenha durado 24h ou mais fique registrada somente a parte de horas, ignorando a parte superior a 24h. Por exemplo, se uma chamada durou 25 horas, 59 minutos e 10 segundos o resultado final será 1h59min10s

Eis código SQL para mostrar o erro que pode ocorrer:

```
-- código #1
declare @I datetime, @F datetime;
set @I= '20100101 01:00';
set @F= '20100102 02:59:10';

SELECT @I, @F, 
       datediff (second, @I, @F), 
       convert (time(0), dateadd (second, datediff (second, @I, @F), 0));
```

---

Para verificar a consistência dos dados rode o seguinte código:

```
-- código #2 v2
SELECT INICOLIGACAO, FINALLIGACAO,
       datediff (hour, INICOLIGACAO, FINALLIGACAO) as DURAÇÃO
  from tabela
  where cast (DIA as date) = '2019-10-30' 
        and CAMPANHA = '1'
        and datediff (hour, INICOLIGACAO, FINALLIGACAO) >= 24;
```

O código acima lista chamadas cuja duração foi maior ou igual a 24 horas, o que representa perda de informação ao converter para TIME(0).

---

Para saber qual é a versão do SQL Server em uso bem como o nível de compatibilidade do banco de dados, rode

```
-- código #3
PRINT @@version
--
SELECT name, compatibility_level
  from sys.databases
  where name = 'nomedobanco';
```

Substitua `nomedobanco` pelo nome do banco de dados.

Comment: quando coloco o  DATEDIFF_BIG() ele da um erro:'DATEDIFF_BIG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @PauloHenrique **(1)** Então ou a versão do SQL Server é anterior a 2016 ou o nível de compatibilidade do banco de dados está ajustado para valor inferior a 130. **(2)** Acrescentei o código #2, para você verificar a consistência dos dados. **(3)** O código #3 permite você verificar qual é a versão do SQL Server bem como o nível de compatibilidade do banco de dados.

Answer (score 2):

> [`DATEDIFF`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> ... Para **segundo**, a diferença máxima é de 68 anos, 19 dias, 3 horas, 14 minutos e 7 segundos.

Como a própria documentação diz, a diferença máxima entre duas datas, em segundos, é a citada acima. Portanto, apesar de não saber quais são os dados da sua tabela, concluo que **os dados contidos em suas colunas estejam incorretos ou que o formato de data apresentada não seja a esperada pelo banco de dados** afinal 68 anos para uma ligação é um montante inconsistente.

A partir do `SQL Server 2016` você pode usar a função `DATEDIFF_BIG` que não possui um limite tão "escasso".

> [`DATEDIFF_BIG`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> Essa função retorna a contagem (como um grande valor inteiro com sinal) dos limites de `datepart` especificados cruzados entre os parâmetros especificados `startdate` e `enddate`.

---

Você pode verificar a versão do `SQL Server` executando o seguinte comando:

```
SELECT @@VERSION AS versao
```

> [`@@VERSION`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/version-transact-sql-configuration-functions?view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> Retorna informações de compilação e sistema para a instalação atual do SQL Server.

Comment: O responsável pelo voto negativo pode esclarecer qual o problema na resposta para que possa ser corrigido?